# <img> tag syntax: <img src="image.jpg"> or <img src="image.jpg"/>?

Tags: html, image, syntax

So I have been coding for a little bit now and have noticed something about the `<img>` tag. I have always closed this tag using `<img src="image.jpg">`, however, I have noticed that some programmers have used `<img src="image.jpg"/>`.

Can someone please clarify for me and maybe others who have the same question which is the correct syntax?

Thank you~!

Comment: I think you could find a proper answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Comment: Thank you everyone for redirecting the post to some very useful references. Because this post seems to be a duplicate, should I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 standard defines a void element, like img (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements and img https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#elementdef-img

```
<img src='my.png'>
```

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements

Whereas XHTML needs it to be closed

```
<img src='my.png' /> <!-- Self Closing -->
<img src='my.png'></img> <!-- "normal" closing -->
```